# How to setup include for all PHP scripts of a directory?

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and I have a very basic questions. I'd like to setup PEAR logging across all PHP files of my project. How do I accomplish that? Right now, in every single file the following lines:

```
// Repeated lines
require_once 'Log.php';
$conf = array('mode' => 0600, 'timeFormat' => '%X %x');
$logger = Log::singleton('file', 'out.log', 'ident', $conf);

// Some logging...
$logger->log("Log entry");
```

Repeating the 3 lines doesn't seem to be the right solution to me. I actually have the same issues with my Propel generated classes. How can I resolve this?

Martin

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a global include file that does all the general things you need to do on every page. For example, if you'd want to instantiate your logger, connect to a database, and do things with a user's `$_SESSION` on every page, you could create a global include:

in /includes/global.php

```
require_once 'Log.php';
$conf = array('mode' => 0600, 'timeFormat' => '%X %x');
$logger = Log::singleton('file', 'out.log', 'ident', $conf);

// Connect to DB

// Do $_SESSION stuff
```

in /any/other/file.php

```
require_once( '/includes/global.php');

// $logger is already defined:
$logger->log("Log entry");
```

If you ever needed to log inside a function, you can either grab a copy of your singleton, or use the `global` keyword:

```
function test( $a)
{
    global $logger;
    $logger->log( 'test() - ' . $a);
}
```

**Edit:** Finally, you can use the [php.ini directive](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) `auto_prepend_file` which specifies the name of a file that is automatically parsed before the main file.

Answer (score 0):

Move the three lines into a separate file and `require_once` that one.

File "MyLog.php":

```
require_once 'Log.php';
$conf = array('mode' => 0600, 'timeFormat' => '%X %x');
$logger = Log::singleton('file', 'out.log', 'ident', $conf);
```

Other files:

```
require_once 'MyLog.php';
$logger->log("Log entry");
```